# Opacity and blur

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to recreate the below effect on the navigationBar on my tabBar. However it does not seem to be transparent. i've been following this tutorial, but does not seem to work. What do i need in order to recreate it?

[image]

In my tabBarController class

```
    tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 90.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
    tabBar.translucent = false
   tabBar.tintColor = UIColor(rgba: "#B52519")


    var underlayView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tabBar.frame.size.width, tabBar.frame.size.height))
    underlayView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
    underlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.34, blue: 0.62, alpha: 1.0)
    underlayView.alpha = 0.36
    tabBar.insertSubview(underlayView, atIndex: 1)
```

Comment: You think that is a picture of a tab bar?

Comment: Nope it is a picture of a navigationBar, but i would like to apply the same effect in this navigationBar into a tabBar

Comment: The thing is that the built-in blur has greatly changed since the day that tutorial was written.

Comment: okay but there is no difference when i said transculent to true

Comment: The thing is that you won't obtain that exact blur easily any more. You are better off just using a UIVisualEffectView and accepting its blur. But it won't be the same.

Comment: thats sad, from a designers point of view. i've been looking on the UIVisualEffect, but did not seem to fit my need. but thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply set `tabBar.translucent = true` instead of the whole `underlayView`.

To change the tint color set `tabBar.barStyle = .Black` to get it to be like the navigation bar effect in your picture.
 If you want to set a custom tint color then set `tabBar.barTintColor` to anything you want.

Read more about Tab Bars in general and Tab Bars Translucency here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UITabBar.html

Comment: that will not give the same effect as in the image

Comment: transculent blur is way more blurry